# What is the most efficient way to signal node.js from Java/MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, performance, node.js

I need to signal a node.js server (any websocket server will do) from a Java application that runs real time (and is time sensitive) on every MySQL operation.

I'm looking for the best option and so far came up with:

***a) A trigger on MySQL***
MySQL would then, on it's own, signal the websocket server to push the update to the client.

**b) Java App call server**
Java would signal node.js/whatever to push new data to the clients.

I would assume having MySQL handle the workload of signaling node.js would be more efficient for the Java App (that is time sensitive).

**Is there a third alternative?** Is it better than those described bellow?

Answer (score 2):

You should use something like [Redis](https://redis.io) or [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) to create a communication channel between Java and Node. Java would send a message through that channel, Node will intercept it and push to MySQL which will respond back when it's done.

Seems pretty ok to me, since Java won't wait for any response and because of the async communication between Node and MySQL (with callbacks and triggers).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to determine which entity/activity is logically generating signals. Is it really the insert on MySQL or the insert performed by Java application. Are there any other applications modifying the MySQL DB? If not, I'd personally post all the events to a queue (another process) which the node.js server would listen to. Using a queue which has clients for both Java and Node.js would help here. This way the load on the database would be minimized and the architecture would be DB/application independent (assuming you are posting updates to the queue from all applications which use MySQL).

An example of one such queue would be [Beanstalkd](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/wiki/client-libraries).